# Base32 alphabet that is an overlapping superset of hexadecimal? (math/CS)

Tags: math, encoding, number-formatting, radix

This is maybe more of a math question, but I'm stumped on it:

Let's say I have an 8-digit hex string. That can represent values from 0 to 2^32-1. Now let's say I want to have an 8-digit string of another base like base32. Is it possible to construct an alphabet for base32 (or another base) that is a strict superset of hexadecimal so that any hex string below 2^32-1 will decode via base32 to the same value and only larger values >=2^32 start incorporating base32 characters outside the hex range?

In other words is it possible to "upgrade" from base 16 to a higher numbered base in a way that is backward compatible with hex identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign numbers to 8-character strings however you like.

There are 2<sup>32</sup> 8-character hex strings, to which you can certainly assign their hex values.

There are 2<sup>40</sup> 8-character strings with characters in, say, 0123456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXY.  2<sup>32</sup> are hex strings, and the remaining 2<sup>40</sup> - 2<sup>32</sup> strings can be assigned any numbers you like.

You won't be able to assign them numbers via a "normal" decimal-like system, however, because hex requres "10" to be 16, not 32.  There are ways that aren't that hard, however.  For example, given a 40-bit number:

1. Convert the lower 32-bits to 8 character HEX.
2. Assign one of the remaining bits to each character, and for each one bit, add 'G' to the corresponding character, changing its range from '0-F' to 'G-Y'

Now you have a string for each 40-bit number, and the smaller ones have the same strings as their hex representations.

Comment: Thanks! That's a direction I hadn't thought of and would probably work!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you right; please correct me if I am wrong. Anyway:

A hex digit (base 16) is represented by 4 bits. Its range is 0000 … 1111, representing digits 0 … F.
An 8-digit hex string is thus represented by 32 bits, that can represent values from 0 to 2^32-1. Its range is 00000000 … FFFFFFFF.

Lets consider a base 17 system, called here a 17dec system.
A 17dec digit (base 17) is represented by 5 bits. Its range is 00000 … 11111, representing digits 0 … V (using a standard Latin alphabet).
A 8-digit 17dec string is thus represented by 40 bits, that can represent values from 0 to 2^40-1.   Its range is 00000000 … VVVVVVVV.

Thus, hex and 17dec cover the same bit combinations from 0 to 2^32-1. It is thus not possible to have a number system with a higher base that is bit-wise compatible with a lower base system.

Take, e.g. the value 10000.
The hex representation of 10000 is 10.
The 17dec representation of 10000 is G.
There is no way to make this compatible.